# Convert form-body into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, regex, http

I am creating my own api interface for my python application (for whatever reason :))

I am able to get my **request body** in a form-data string e.g

```
"name=prakashraman&tvshows%5B%5D=lost&tvshows%5B%5D=buffy"
```

I would like that be converted to

```
{ 
   "name": "prakashraman",
   "tvshows": ["lost", "buffy"]
}
```

Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one naive way to do this:

```
s = "name=prakashraman&tvshows%5B%5D=lost&tvshows%5B%5D=buffy"

d = {}
for x in s.split('&'):
    k, sep, v = x.partition('=')
    if sep != '=':
       raise ValueError('malformed query')
    k = k.split('%')[0]
    if k in d:
       if isinstance(d[k], list): d[k].append(v)
       else: d[k] = [d[k], v]
    else:
      d[k] = v

print(d)
# {'name': 'prakashraman', 'tvshows': ['lost', 'buffy']}
```

However, if you need to keep your output standardised as a QueryDict, the easy way is to use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) (in Python 2: [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)) on the string:

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> s = "name=prakashraman&tvshows%5B%5D=lost&tvshows%5B%5D=buffy"
>>> parse.parse_qs(s)
{'name': ['prakashraman'], 'tvshows[]': ['lost', 'buffy']}
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks! I think I might use it :) Although, would it work for deeper next [] arrays?

Comment: @PrakashRaman Yes, it should. The `isinstance(d[k], list)` branch handles continuous *appends* to an existing key.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I guess, this is my best option for now!

Comment: Surprising there isn't a support library for this operation.

Comment: @PrakashRaman There's `urllib`. And if the answer helped, you may consdier accepting it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess I was being greedy :) And hoping for a better/easier solution. Although with looking around your solution seems to be closest to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @PrakashRaman Ah, no problem. You can accept newer answers if they come. It's not permanent :)